# During account creation, is it better to generate the password automatically and send it to the user, or to let the user create his own password?

Tags: security, passwords

This question came up today while discussing with a colleague about the 'create account' page for the website we're working on.

My colleague's opinion is that we should make the registration as quick and seamless as possible, therefore we should just ask the user for his email and take care of the rest.

I agree with the intention, but I have a few concerns about it:

- Since we generate the password, we *have* the responsibility to make sure the password is strong enough
- In my experience, when confronted with an unintelligible password, users are likely to write it down on a post it
- The users who do not write the password down, are pretty likely to forget it. Which means they'll have to ask for a new password regularly, and that's not fun for anyone

However, considering the general quality of passwords created by users, and the fact that too many people tend to use the same password for everything ('shudders'), I can see how it would make sense to generate a strong password for them.

I still feel torn about it. We are working on a merchant website where the user has the option to save his credit card details, so it is obviously very important that we use most secure approach.

Comment: I suppose someone has to reference this: [xkcd: Password Strength](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: @CandledOrange Obligatory XKCD reference

Comment: As a consumer, the moment I use your site and _you generate a password for me_ is the moment I delete my account.

Comment: @Eirc King: I feel you. I use my own mental patterns to create long passwords. Arbitrary restrictions (limited length, no special characters, etc) and generated passwords are things I hate with a passion. However, I need to put my feelings aside and only look at the security aspect.

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com). There is already a similar question with interesting answers as well: [Would you get rid of password field in sign-up form](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/79817/22919).

Comment: Emails are not a secure communication channel. Do not send passwords via email. Tokens that are only valid for a short amount of time (e.g 24 hrs) might be ok. You can't avoid passwords, but you may encourage use of password managers: dedicated software, "remember my password" browser features, and physical notebooks are all legit strategies. Providing a password does not encourage good security habits. Additionally implement login options like "sign in with Google" where you don't store passwords. Use external payment processors so that I don't have to trust your site with my payment details.

Comment: I agree, as a user, providing a password is preferable than receiving one per mail to change anyway. The other option is OAuth, where you don't even have to use/store passwords at the price of a more complex server worklow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The advntage of the email approach is that you ensure by this way that the user did provide a valid email account that he/she controls.

However, the email channel is notoriously insecure. This means that the password could be intercepted. So this approach should only be considered if the generated password is used only once, at first login, and if it's ensured that the user must change it.

The direct approach is more secure, in the sense that a tls/ssl connection to your website is much more difficult to intercept without being noticed.

Comment: Usually, both approaches are used together: enter email and password, then receive an email containing an activation link.

Comment: @mouviciel yes, en effet. This two-step approach with password and link seems to be the most common approach used, and certainly not without reason :-) It's safer, because in general the activation link is only used for activation and  not for login.  For the OP, this would require the development of the logic for sending the activation link and tracking of activation on account.